# Ubuntu 20.04, FPCupDeluxe 3.3.1, Lazarus 2.1.0 on MacBookPro 2012, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, lazarus

My problem is with the display of pages in FPCUpdeluxe and in test sites in lazarus. You may see images in this thread https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,51359.0.html. It seems that the pages are not displayed dynamic but fixed - making them hard to read. Hope someone may be able to help. Have tried to change resolution etc. with Tweak and dconf Editor but in vain. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Ran an update operation, and got a message that some(?) packages were upgradeable. Upgraded (?) changed the resolution to 1920x1200 and the scale to 100? Then fcpupdeluxe looked OK. Still the log window has tiny text - which doesn't match pictures from other sites. I anticipate this solves my problem.